# dynamically allocate space for varying size structures array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, memory-management, dynamic, allocation

I'm facing a problem that seems complicated to me so i'll be very grateful to who can help me.

I'm sort of trying to replicate the array of string behavior only with structures
so instead of having for example

```
char **mys={"hello","this is a long message"};
```

I'm trying to have an array with structures (each structure containing an array of variable length). I'm not quite sure if I exposed my problem very well so i hope the code is going to indicate what i'm trying to do:

my two structures :

```
typedef struct
{
    int *iTab;
    int iTail;
}strDynArr;

typedef struct
{
    strDynArr **iTab;
    int iTailStruct;
    int iTail;
}strDynDynArr;
```

All the functions related to those two structures :

```
void initArray(strDynArr *ar)
{
    ar->iTab=malloc(sizeof(int));
    ar->iTail=1;
}

void pushArray(int iElement,strDynArr *ar)
{
    ar->iTab[ar->iTail-1]=iElement;
    realloc(ar->iTab,(ar->iTail++)*sizeof(int));
}

void freeDynArray(strDynArr *ar)
{
    free(*ar->iTab);
}

void initDynDynArray(strDynDynArr *ar)
{
    ar->iTab=malloc(sizeof(int));
    ar->iTail=1;
    ar->iTailStruct=1;
}

//the problem
void pushDynDynArray(strDynArr *daElement,strDynDynArr *ar)
{
    //ar->iTab[ar->iTail-1]=daElement;
    ar->iTailStruct+=(daElement->iTail+1);
    realloc(ar->iTab,(ar->iTailStruct)*sizeof(int));
    ar->iTab[ar->iTailStruct-(daElement->iTail+1)]=daElement;
    //realloc(ar->iTab,(ar->iTail++)*sizeof(int));
}
void freeDynDynDynArray(strDynDynArr *ar)
{
    free(*ar->iTab);
}
```

And the one function where i'm stuck is pushDynDynArray so far i've attempted two things either just using the pointer that points on à structure strDynArr but i don't know how space is managed at all so i tryed to allocate the size of the all the structures contained in the array of the structure strDynDynArr.

So what i would like to know is how to allocate space for my array (iTab) for a structure of type strDynDynArr.

In other words what is the way for me to store several structures containing for example :

```
//content of structure 1
int *iTab={2,3,4};
int iTail=3;

//content of structure 2
int *iTab={5,8,9,10,54,8,2};
int iTail=7;
```

All help is welcome and thanks à lot for it !

Comment: Note: To accept an answer, click on the OK mark below the up and down arrows to the left of the top of the answer. This causes the question to show up with the number of votes in green background in the lists, which indicates it is solved; there is no need to add SOLVED to the question either.

Comment: Thanks didn't see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, lets call each array of "strings" a table (of arrays), and each "string" an array of items. In your case, the item type seems to be `int`:

```
typedef int  item;

typedef struct {
    size_t  size;   /* Number of items allocated for */
    size_t  used;   /* Number of items in item[] */
    item   *item;
} array;

typedef struct {
    size_t  size;   /* Number of array (pointers) allocated for */
    size_t  used;   /* Number of arrays in array[] */
    array  *array;
} table;
```

It is common to define initializer macros and functions for such types:

```
#define  ARRAY_INIT  { 0, 0, NULL }
#define  TABLE_INIT  { 0, 0, NULL }

static inline void array_init(array *ref)
{
    if (!ref) {
        fprintf(stderr, "array_init(): NULL array!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ref->size = 0;
    ref->used = 0;
    ref->item = NULL;
}

static inline void table_init(table *ref)
{
    if (!ref) {
        fprintf(stderr, "table_init(): NULL table!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ref->size = 0;
    ref->used = 0;
    ref->array = NULL;
}
```

Also, free functions are obviously useful:

```
static inline void array_free(array *ref)
{
    if (!ref) {
        fprintf(stderr, "array_free(): NULL array!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    free(ref->item); /* Note: free(NULL) is safe; it does nothing. */
    ref->size = 0;
    ref->used = 0;
    ref->item = NULL;
}

static inline void table_free(table *ref)
{
    size_t  i;

    if (!ref) {
        fprintf(stderr, "table_free(): NULL table!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    i = ref->size;
    while (i-->0)
        array_free(ref->array + i); /* array_free(&(ref->array[i])); */

    free(ref->array);
    ref->size = 0;
    ref->used = 0;
    ref->array = NULL;
}
```

When freeing a table, we want to free all (possible) arrays individually, then the memory used by the pointers.  Note that one could assume that only `used` arrays are in use; however, I wanted the above to be thorough, and free all `size` arrays allocated for.

Both the init and free functions above take a pointer to an array or table. They should never be NULL. (That is, the `item` or `array` *member* in the structure may well be NULL; it's just that you should never call e.g. `array_init(NULL);` or `table_free(NULL)`.)

Let us implement a function to push and pop individual ints from a solitary array (that may or may not be part of a table):

```
void array_push(array *ref, const item value)
{
    if (!ref) {
        fprintf(stderr, "array_push(): NULL array!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Need to grow the array? */
    if (ref->used >= ref->size) {
        size_t  size; /* Minimum is ref->used + 1 */
        void   *temp;

        /* Dynamic growth policy. Pulled from a hat. */
        if (ref->used < 64)
            size = 64;  /* Minimum 64 elements */
        else
        if (ref->used < 1048576)
            size = (3*ref->used) / 2; /* Grow by 50% up to 1048576 */
        else
            size = (ref->used | 1048575) + 1048577; /* Grow to next multiple of 1048576 */

        temp = realloc(ref->item, size * sizeof ref->item[0]);
        if (!temp)
            return -1; /* Out of memory */

        ref->item = temp;
        ref->size = size;
    }

    /* Append value to array. */
    ref->item[ref->used++] = value;
}
```

and a corresponding pop operation:

```
item array_pop(array *ref)
{
    if (!ref) {
        fprintf(stderr, "array_pop(): NULL array!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (ref->used < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "array_pop(): Array is already empty; nothing to pop.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Since ref->used is the *number* of items in the array,
       we want to decrement it first, to get the last item in array. */
    return ref->item[--ref->used];
}
```

In your program, you can use an array for example thus:

```
array  scores = ARRAY_INIT;

array_push(&scores, 5);
array_push(&scores, 2);

printf("%d\n", array_pop(&scores)); /* Will print 2 */
printf("%d\n", array_pop(&scores)); /* Will print 5 */

array_free(&scores);
```

The line `array scores = ARRAY_INIT;` both declares and initializes the array (to an empty array). You could also equivalently use `array scores; array_init(&scores);`.

The resize or growth policy in `array_push()` is roughly along the lines I'd personally recommend, although the actual numerical values are pulled from a hat, and you may wish to adjust them.  The idea is that there is a minimum number of items allocated for (say, 64). For bigger arrays, we increase the size fractionally, so that when the array is large, the size increase is also large. Many people use 100% increase in size (doubling the size, i.e. `size = 2 * ref->used;`), but I like 50% increase better (multiplying the size by one and one half, `size = (3 * ref->used) / 2;`). For huge arrays, we don't want to waste potentially lots of memory, so we allocate in fixed-size (but huge) chunks instead. (There is no need or real benefit to align the huge size to some multiple like I did; I just like it that way. And the more complicated code ensures you need to understand it and edit it, rather than submitting it raw as yours; otherwise, you'll instructor will catch you cheating.)

Pushing a single value to the last array in the table is now simple to implement:

```
void table_push_value(table *ref, const item value)
{
    size_t  i;

    if (!ref) {
        fprintf(stderr, "table_push_value(): NULL table!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Ensure there is at least one array. */
    if (!ref->size < 1) {
        /* Empty table: ref->size = 0, and ref->used must be 0 too. */
        const size_t  size = 1; /* Allocate for exactly one array. */
        void         *temp;

        temp = realloc(ref->array, size * sizeof ref->array[0]);
        if (!temp) {
            fprintf(stderr, "table_push_value(): Out of memory.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        ref->size = size;
        ref->array = temp;

        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            array_init(ref->array + i); /* array_init(&(ref->array[i])); */
    }

    if (ref->used > 0)
        i = ref->used - 1;  /* Last array in table */
    else
        i = 0; /* Table is empty, so use first array */

    array_push(ref->array + i, value); /* array_push(&(ref->array[i])); */
}
```

This time, you need special logic for an empty table, for both allocating the description for an array, as well as where to push.

Pop is simpler:

```
item table_pop_value(table *ref)
{
    size_t  i;

    if (!ref) {
        fprintf(stderr, "table_pop_value(): NULL table!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    i = ref->used;

    /* Find the last array with items in it, and pop from it. */
    while (i-- > 0)
        if (ref->array[i].used > 0) {
            return array_pop(ref->array + i); /* array_pop(&(ref->array[i])); */

    fprintf(stderr, "table_pop_value(): Empty table, no items to pop!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

To push an entire array to a table (pushing the array of items in it, not making a copy of the items) is pretty simple, but we do need to implement a reallocation/growth policy again:

```
void table_push_array(table *ref, array *one)
{
    if (!ref) {
        fprintf(stderr, "table_push_array(): NULL table!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (!one) {
        fprintf(stderr, "table_push_array(): NULL array!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (ref->used >= ref->size) {
        size_t  size, i;
        void   *temp;

        if (ref->used < 1)
            size = 1;  /* Minimum size is 1 */
        else
            size = (ref->used | 7) + 9; /* Next multiple of 8 */

        temp = realloc(ref->array, size * sizeof ref->array[0]);
        if (!temp) {
            fprintf(stderr, "table_push_array(): Out of memory.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        ref->array = temp;
        for (i = ref->size; i < size; i++)
            array_init(ref->array + i); /* array_init(&(ref->array[i])); */
        ref->size = size;
    }

    ref->array[ref->used] = *one; /* "shallow copy" */
    ref->used++;
}
```

The corresponding pop operation should be pretty obvious by now:

```
array *table_pop_array(table *ref)
{
    array  retval = ARRAY_INIT;

    if (!ref) {
        fprintf(stderr, "table_pop_array(): NULL table!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (ref->used < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "table_pop_array(): Table is empty, no arrays to pop!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }        

    /* Decrement the used count, so it refers to the last array in the table. */
    ref->used--;

    /* Shallow copy the array. */
    retval = ref->array[ref->used];

    /* Init, but do not free, the array in the table. */
    array_init(ref->array + ref->used); /* array_init(&(ref->array[ref->used)); */

    /* Return the array. */
    return retval;
}
```

There is a "trick" in `table_pop_array()` above, that you should understand. While we cannot return pointers to local variables, we can return structures. In the above case, the structure describes the array, and the pointer in it does not refer to a local variable, but to a dynamically allocated array of items. Structure types can be assigned just as normal scalar types (like `int` or `double`); it is basically the same as if you assigned each member separately.

Overall, you should notice I have not used a single `malloc()` call. This is because `realloc(NULL, size)` is equivalent to `malloc(size)`, and simply initializing unused pointers to NULL makes everything simpler.

When a table is grown (reallocated), we do need to initialize all the new arrays, because of the above `realloc()` use pattern.

The above approach does not preclude direct access to specific arrays in the table, or specific items in an array. If you intend to implement such functions, two helper functions similar to

```
void table_need_arrays(table *ref, const size_t size);
void array_need_items(array *ref, const size_t size);
```

that ensure that the table has room for at least `size` arrays, and an array has room for at least `size` items. They are also useful when pushing multiple items or arrays consecutively, as then one can do e.g. `table_need_arrays(&mytable, mytable.used + 10);` to ensure there is room for additional 10 arrays in the table.

All throughout the functions above, you can see notation `name_of_array + index`, and a comment with corresponding `&(name_of_array[index])`. This is because the two notations are equivalent: pointer to the `index`'th element in `name_of_array`.

I didn't bother to compile-check the above code, so there might be typos hidden in there. (This too is intentional, because I want you to understand the code, and not just copy it and use it as your own without understanding any of the details.) However, the logic is sound. So, if you find a typo or issue, let me know in a comment, and I shall fix.